# Синхронизация локальных файлов с файлами на ftp

Tags: файлы, php, синхронизация

Задача: Есть локальный файлы(они могут изменится), есть папка на ftp. Нужно реализовать так что бы происходила синхронизация между локальными файлами и ftp. Т.е если файл не изменился, то пропустить. Если изменился - загрузить. Если появился новый - загрузить.
Реализовал:
Написал несколько функций, схематично так:

1. Функция1, ищет все файлы в локальном каталоге и записывает их в файл local.baz в виде
    "имя файла-----размер файла"
2. Функция2 делает тоже самое но только с ftp файлами, создаёт локально файл remote.baz и записывает туда информацию по всем файлам на ftp в виде "имя файла-----размер файла"
3. Функция3 сравнивает построчно две базы, local.baz и remote.baz и принимает решение - о закачивание файла на ftp.
4. Функция4 закачки на ftp

Возможно я намудрил, так как тернистым путём php программера иду(самоучка). Возникает такой трабл, что функция 3 точно определяет что файл из local.baz есть в файле remote.baz, но всё равно выполняет функцию загрузки на ftp. Почему так, не пойму, подскажите - кто силён. Или дайте идею для более легкой реализации, чем я тут придумал.
Кусок кода где стоит условие и принятие решения о загрузке на ftp

---

```
function sravnenie_remot_local($file_name_local, $file_name_remote) {
    $rename_pravilo = "/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/";
    if ($handle_local1 = fopen($file_name_local, "r"))
        echo "файл $file_name_local открыт";
    if ($file_local_mas = fread($handle_local1, filesize($file_name_local)))
        echo "<br> прочитал $file_name_local<br>";

//получаем массив содержимого файлов
    $fopen_files_local = file($file_name_local);
    $fopen_files_remote = file($file_name_remote);

    //цикл обработки локальной базы расширения .baz
    foreach ($fopen_files_local as $v_loc) {

        echo " --локальный ".$v_loc."<br>";
        //вложенный цикл обработки удалённой базы
        foreach ($fopen_files_remote as $v_rem) {
            echo "Сравниваем файлы<br>"."--удаленный ".$v_rem."<br>";
            $ravno=strcmp($v_loc, $v_rem);
            if ($ravno!==0) {

                echo "<br>$v_loc=НЕ РАВНО=$v_rem<br>";
                echo "<br>Если вижу значит условие прошло<br>";
                //Обратное преобразование имени с размером в обычное имя
                preg_match($rename_pravilo, $v_loc, $v_loc_rename);
                foreach ($v_loc_rename as $v_loc_final_name) {
                    //загрузка на ftp
                   ftp_nod_upload($v_loc_final_name);
                    echo "Файл $v_loc_final_name загружен ---- Условие завершено<br>";

                }
            } else {
                echo "Обратное условие началось<br>Файл $v_loc_final_name <strong>ПРОПУЩЕН</strong><br>";

            } 
        }
    }
    echo "<br>Загрузка завершена<br>";
    ftp_close($antona_connect);

    if ($handle_remote11 = fopen($file_name_remote, "r"))
        echo "<br> Файл $file_name_remote окткрыт ";
    if (fread($handle_remote11, filesize($file_name_remote)))
        echo "<br> прочитал $file_name_remote"; }
```

Comment: Хорошая идея, спасибо. Попробую сейчас сделать это - как вариант.

Comment: Сравниваете md5 размеров файлов. Не сходятся хеши - срочно обновить!

Comment: @lampa ИМХО, не универсально и в файле может поменяться всего один знак, а размер не измениться. Нормально работать будет при условии, что файл постоянно растёт в размере.
@northmule а у вас какая конкретно задача? Что храниться в файлах?

Comment: @lampa беру свои слова назад: если файлы под очень большие, то действительно проще сравнивать хеш от размера.

Comment: @zenith тогда сравнивать дату изменения файла. Про размер, конечно, вы правы!

Comment: Вероятность того что изменится один знак практически нулевая. Задача выгружать файлы антивирусных баз на удаленный ftp, что бы от туда могли обновляться клиенты. Реализовал по изменению md5 размера файла. Добавил еще пару функций для контроля присутствия файлов, а так же их нужности и всё получилось. По сравнению с моим первоначальным кодом и идеей реализации - получилось всё гораздо короче и быстрее в работе, но повысилась нагрузка на на ЦП(но это позволительно). Всем спасибо за идеи, оч помогли!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вникал в Ваш код, но попробуйте вычислять md5 для файлов, к примеру, раз в час. И обновлять те файлы, у которых хешь не сошёлся.
В теории это быстрее, чем построчное сравнение и даст результат при любом изменении файла.